# Error with expected operator before token

Tags: c

The error is telling me I'm missing an operator somewhere, but I simply cannot see it so I figured some fresh eyes could help me find it.

Code snippet:

```
static int min_val, max_val;

struct arrNum
{
    int charged;                    
    int count;                      
};

static struct arrNum nums[];
static int max_num = 0;

static void sort_order(int iNum)
{
    if (iNum < 0)
        return;

    if (iNum > max_num)
        max_num = iNum;

    struct arrNum nums[iNum].charged = 1;
    struct arrNums nums[iNum].count++;

    return;
}
```

Errors:

```
mergeSort.c: In function 'sort_order':
mergeSort.c:32:29: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
     struct arrNum nums[iNum].charged = 1;
                             ^
mergeSort.c:32:29: error: expected expression before '.' token
mergeSort.c:33:30: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
     struct arrNums nums[iNum].count++;
                              ^
mergeSort.c:33:30: error: expected expression before '.' token
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: You confuse struct declaration and use. Remove `struct arrNum` and `struct arrNums` from the last two lines before the `return`. (Also, you have an extra "s" in one of the struct names.)

Comment: You don't need the `return;` at the end of a `void` function; that's what happens if you omit the line.

Comment: @DYZ Thank you! I added that stuff in because I was getting undefined reference to nums error, but now I've fixed that so I can do what you said and it compiles now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for pointing that out! I've removed the unnecessary return now.

Answer (score 0):

here is a version of the code with comments:

```
// following two statements will cause the compiler to raise
// warning messages because this statements 
// declare the variables, but they are never used
static int min_val;   
static int max_val;  

// define a struct with two fields
struct arrNum
{
    int charged;
    int count;
};

// declare an instance of a pointer to a struct
// actually want an array of `struct arrNum`
// so need a number between the '[' and ']'
// it must be given a size that is at least 1 greater 
// than the highest value of 'iNum'
static struct arrNum nums[];  

static int max_num = 0;

// following line will raise a compiler warning
// because 'static' function can only be referenced in the current file
// and nothing in the posted code calls it.
static void sort_order(int iNum)
{
    if (iNum < 0)
        return;

    if (iNum > max_num)
        max_num = iNum;

                              // note: both following statements are 
                              // writing into 'la la land' 
                              // because all that has been declared for 
                              // 'nums[]' is a pointer
                              // and because it is declared 'static'
                              // is initialized to 0
                              // so executing either of these statements
                              // will result in a seg fault event
    nums[iNum].charged = 1;   // nums[] already declared, so don't declare it again
    nums[iNum].count++;       // nums[] already declared, so don't declare it again
}
```